# Operations research | Employee availability problem

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, operations-research, binary-programming

So I have a problem with school and I am not sure if it is a employee schedueling problem, here is the situation:

We have to minimize the amount of employees at a non profit organization(Sanquin) and we have to optimize it for 3 locations. Here is the given info:
$x_{ij}$ = 1 if employee has started shift i on day j; = 0 else.

And I have the amount of employees needed noted as a parameter p --> $p_i$ = amount of employees needed.

Monday: open from 12:30 - 20:00, amount of employees needed is here each half hour:
12:30 - 13:00 --> 2
13:00 - 13:30 --> 2
13:30 - 14:00 --> 2
14:00 - 14:30 --> 4
14:30 - 15:00 --> 2
15:00 - 15:30 --> 3
15:30 - 16:00 --> 5
16:00 - 16:30 --> 6
16:30 - 17:00 --> 5
17:00 - 17:30 --> 7
17:30 - 18:00 --> 5
18:00 - 18:30  --> 7
18:30 - 19:00 --> 8
19:00 - 19:30 --> 8
19:30 - 20:00 --> 7

Then I have the goal function:
$$Z = \sum_{i=0}^8 x_{i1} \cdot p_i$$
$s.t            x_{ij} \ge p_i $

With $x_{ij} = {0,1 } $
and $\mathbb{N}$

Now my question: how can I apply this to different locations and different days, because different days have different $p_i$. One of my thoughts were $\sum_{i=0}^8 \sum_{j=1}^5 x_{ij}$

Oh and the shifts can sometimes vary from day to day, so I have written that all out per day, but I want it all written out in 1 single formula in 1 location if possible, the main goal is to simplify it.

Comment: Would integer programming be also the best solution here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign employees to each of the shifts by mixed integer (binary) otherwise the solver will just assign the largest number of employees $x$ in your case to satisfy the constraints -shift requiring the most number of employees.
If you already have a list of employees $E$, hen your variable will be binary $ x_{s,d}^{e,l} = 1$ if employee $e$ is assigned o shift $s$ on day $d$ at location $l$ else $0$.
If you're not sure how many employees, take it as $N$ where $N$ is the maximum of employees needed by any shift at any location.
You may need pre-determined combination of sets like employee-location ($ E,L)$ and parameters like maximum number of shifts per day for an employee $S_e$

Obj $\min \sum_{e,l}\sum_{s,d}x_{s,d}^{e,l}$
s.t.
$ \sum_e x_{s,d}^{e,l} \ge p_{s,d}^l \quad \forall s,d,l$
$\sum_s x_{s,d}^{e,l} \le S_e \quad \forall e,l,d$